# Обновление базы access из DataGridView(winforms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, ms-access

Есть `DataGridView`, с ним связана база  `access` , и `button`, при нажатии на который все изменения в `DataGridView` должны сохраняться в базу. В VisualStudio 2008 можно было это сделать при помощи `this.tableBillsTableAdapter.Update(this.dbBillsDataSet.TableBills);`
 но в VS 2015 не находит метод Update, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: дайте больше кода